# Eclipse addes strange files to project. How to stop it?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I use Eclipse + svn plugin.

Also I have tortoise svn.

I faced with unbelievable issue.

I see that my eclipse plugin see that my version of project different by repository.

[image]

I try to make commit and see following:

[image]

then I go to file system and see that this files really exist, I delete it, then make refresh from eclipse and see that these files appear again.

I tryed make:

1. refresh project
2. clean project
3. team->Cleanup
4. reconnect project
5. restart eclipse
6. remove project from Eclipse and filesystem. then download it again.
   and import to eclipse.

I have not success.

What the hell?

How can I fix it?

**P.S.**

If I make update from tortoise svn - these files don't appear on my filesystem.  Thus I think that this files stores in Eclipse cash. how to clean it?

Comment: Those aren't files, they're folders that contain one .java file. You haven't given enough information to explain why it's "strange" or "unexepected."

Comment: @E-Riz these files doesn't exist in repository!!! these files don't exist in file system. These files appear in filesystem after eclipse refresh!!!!